# Grizzly, Jersey and Spring auto-wiring issue

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, jersey, grizzly

I am using Grizzly as a web server to create standalone REST service with Jersey. I also want to use Spring IoC in the application but I ran into problems with auto-wiring beans.

To create the server I run this in my main() method:

```
HttpServer server = null;

try {
    ResourceConfig rc = new PackagesResourceConfig("");
    ConfigurableApplicationContext cac = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath*:/spring-context.xml");          
    IoCComponentProviderFactory factory = new SpringComponentProviderFactory(rc, 

    server = GrizzlyServerFactory.createHttpServer("http://localhost:5555", rc, factory);
    System.in.read();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    try {
       if (server != null) {
          server.stop();
       }
    } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My spring-context.xml contains just below:

```
<context:annotation-config />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.test"/>
```

I want to auto-wire BO object in my Jersey resource class:

```
@Path("/test")
@Service
public class Test {

    @Autowired
    private testBO testBo;
    ....

    @GET
    @Path("/info")
    public String getInfo() {
       return testBo.get();
    }

}
```

Now, whenever I call a method in the Test class that references testBo, I am getting **NullPointerException**, which I think means the bean was not auto-wired.

testBO class has @Component annotation. Also all relevant beans are part of "com.test" package or its subpackages.

Anyone has any idea what am I doing wrong?

As requested stack trace for NullPointerException below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.test.Test.getInfo(Test.java:27)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyContainer._service(GrizzlyContainer.java:215)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.container.grizzly2.GrizzlyContainer.service(GrizzlyContainer.java:185)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.service(HttpHandlerChain.java:195)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:162)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$3.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:95)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:364)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:63)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:823)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:116)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$000(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$1.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:98)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:508)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:488)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

I am also seeing that in the console output:

```
03-Aug-2013 17:46:33 org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@131f71a: startup date [Sat Aug 03 17:46:33 BST 2013]; root of context hierarchy
03-Aug-2013 17:46:33 org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1971afc: defining beans []; root of factory hierarchy
```

Comment: Can you please share detailed log of `NullPointerException`??

Comment: I have included that now. thanks

Comment: Sorry for late reply, Is your application context getting loaded???

Comment: I am not sure, there are no errors but I dont think any beans are getting instantiated.

Comment: What if you invoke getInfo() programmatically? Get Test bean from context and call getInfo(). That way you will see if the problem is happening for your rest service invoked by HTTP get request or if the problem is with your Spring configuration.
Also I do not see you start the server - server.start() - without that I do not think your getInfo() would get called by http request at all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Java 8 - might be worth taking a look at [Microserver](https://github.com/aol/micro-server).

It provides the infrastructure to integrate Grizzly, Jersey 2 and Spring 4.0. If your main method is in package com.test, then all you need is :-

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     new MicroserverApp(()->"context").run();

}
```

Otherwise, you should also annotate your main class with

```
@Microserver(basePackages={"com.test"})
```